# Paperclip/ImageMagick problems on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shell, imagemagick, paperclip, dos

I managed to implement a rounded-corners post-process on my avatars. It works fine on my Mac, but no dice on Windows.

it looks like so

```
def self.convert_options(px = 10)
  trans = ""
  trans << " \\( +clone -alpha extract "
  trans << "-draw 'fill black polygon 0,0 0,#{px} #{px},0 fill white circle #{px},#{px} #{px},0' "
  trans << "\\( +clone -flip \\) -compose Multiply -composite "
  trans << "\\( +clone -flop \\) -compose Multiply -composite "
  trans << "\\) -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite "
end
```

based on http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded & [Rounded corners with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789820/rounded-corners-with-paperclip)

The big list of errors I got kicked off with

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `\\(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
```

I figure maybe it is something to do with Windows escaping characters? So changed the \ to ^ but got this error instead

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `black': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
```

ImageMagick is working, otherwise. It manages simpler processing/resizing fine. And the line produces rounded corner files with no problem if I use GIT BASH to type out the command straight into the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good night's sleep (after hours of trying thousands of combinations) led me to this

```
def self.convert_options_win(px = 10)
  trans = " "
  trans << " ( +clone -alpha extract -draw \"fill black polygon 0,0 0,#{px} #{px},0 fill white circle #{px},#{px} #{px},0 \"  "
  trans << " ( +clone -flip ) -compose Multiply -composite  "
  trans << " ( +clone -flop ) -compose Multiply -composite ) "
  trans << " -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite  "
end
```

which works fine.  No real need for the continuation characters at the start of the line, as it was all being truncated into a single line string. Windows shell prefers "double quotes" to 'single quotes' so just had to escape those within the string.  I tried so many combinations, can't believe it was this simple.